# Setting bounds of Chrome windows with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I frequently switch between setups with my external monitor on different sides, so I'm trying to create a script that sets the bounds for my standard 6 Chrome windows. I think I've figured out the basics, but it seems that the window identifiers aren't consistent (eg. window 1 seems to be whichever window is frontmost when I run the script).

Is there a good way to consistently identify the windows so I can put them in their proper position?